# Absolute path URLs for assets in CSS

Tags: css, reactjs

Why doesn't the absolute path for this asset (the font) work, whereas the relative path works?

```
<body>
  hello friend
</body>
<style type="text/css">
  @font-face {
    font-family: 'Gilroy';
    /* src: url("../src/styles/assets/Gilroy.otf"); */
    src: local('Gilroy')
      url('/Users/username/dev-env/test-react/app/src/styles/assets/Gilroy.otf');
  }
  body {
    font-family: Gilroy;
  }
</style>
```

Edit: It is a problem with React/Babel/Webpack.
[image]

Comment: Maybe that's not the actual absolute path? Why wouldn't you want to use a relative path?

Comment: I'm sure that the path is right. I was just looking into a way to make things easier since I'm actually on a more complex project that I don't really know where the Sass/CSS file will be imported.

Comment: Maybe you should use `!important` after font-family in class body!

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a `,` after the `local()`

```
<style type="text/css">
  @font-face {
    font-family: 'Gilroy';
    src: local('Gilroy'),
      url('/Users/username/dev-env/test-react/app/src/styles/assets/Gilroy.otf');
  }
  body {
    font-family: Gilroy;
  }
</style>
```

See [@font-face examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face#Examples).

Comment: Then copy and paste what works in the URL from the browser. Can you access the file with a browser? For whatever reason you're not releasing the domain so nobody else can really figure it out for you.

Comment: I'm doing this locally. It's not live. And yes, I can access the file from the browser.

Comment: I think this may be a React/Webpack bug.

Comment: Locally? Are you hosting locally with a webserver or are you doing `file://`? Why not use the full URL instead of using a `/` reference to root? That root reference means different things in different context.

Comment: That's not a bug. It's just an error message saying your path doesn't work. Your path is simply wrong... throw the URL into a browser, then COPY the whole thing, including the protocol, into the CSS.